# Unable to use packages (pip) in virtual environment -VS Code

Tags: python, pip

Every-time I create a new virtual environment, I cannot use pip from it. I know that I managed to solve this once, but I dont know how. It just happened.

So here is how I go about creating a venv:

I create a new virtual environment from the VS Code terminal inside my projects folder using `python3 -m venv venv_x`.

I get the pop-up asking if I want to use it and I click yes. It also gets displayed correctly.

[image: Venv activated]

[image: Virtual env location]

But when I try to run pip using `python3 pip` or `python pip` I get `/usr/local/bin/python3: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

Running `which pip` gives no putput.

My `pyvenv.cfg` inside `venv_x/pyvenv.cfg` :

```
home = /usr/local/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.8.6
```

What am i doing wrong? It cant be that hard. So I am probably forgetting something obvious.

Every help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Maybe showing the contents of the venv can help.
But after executing a python script VS Code asks me to install my code formatter black, which after accepted, gets installed by the IDE like this:

`.../dev/test/venv_x/bin/python" /Users/chris/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U black'
The venv packages folder contents gets updated accordingly and black works.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `pip3`?

Comment: Not only for Linux, but it also for Windows. I cannot launch `pip` by `python pip`, it will cause `python: can't open file 'C:\Users\USERNAME\pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Try using `pip3` or `pip` only.

Comment: `python -m pip`, not `python pip`.

Comment: I find it somewhat weird that it still gives Python as `/usr/local/bin/python3`, not one in your v-env. Was the environment properly acitvated.

Comment: @im_baby pip3 cannot be found neither :/

Comment: @00 "pip -m" does install packages, but only globally, not inside the virtual environment.
How can I check if it was activated properly? And yes the path is definitely weird. Especially because if it would take the /bin/ path it should pip, right?

Comment: `pip -m` is not the command, `python -m pip`. That aside, the fact that the packages are installed globally indicates that your virtual environment is *not* activated, and the global Python executable (& friends) is used.

Comment: What is the first line of `main.py`? Is there a hash-bang line, like `#! /usr/local/bin/python` or something similar?

Comment: Yes I used that command ("python3 -m pip") and thank you for helping me :) How do I activate the virtual environment then and make VS Code use it correctly?

Comment: So to summarise: VS code does ask you to activate the virtual environment, but if you then run a script from within VS code, it ignores the virtual environment?

Comment: @00 No, it runs the script inside the venv. VS Code even asks me to install black. This is how it installs black: `.../dev/test/venv_x/bin/python" /Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U black`

Comment: *How*, precisely, are you trying to use `pip`? Do you double-click something in VS code? Do you type it somewhere in a run-box, or in a console? I see an image where you have select the `pip` *package*, but not the binary. Are you using `python` or `pip` inside the `venv_x/bin` directory?

Comment: @00 Sorry I forgot to add that information. I just type in the console. It looks like this `(venv_x) xxx:test chris$ python3 pip install some_package`. (Using the -m parameter installs the package globally.)

Comment: Running `python3 pip` only makes sense if `pip` is in the current directory. The `-m` option executes the `pip` module (which amounts to running the `pip` command), it has nothing to do whether it install globally or locally. If the `-m` option results in a global installation, that means your `python3` executable is global. Try `which python3` (and `which python`, and `which pip`), to see where they are located.

Comment: `which python` ->
`/usr/bin/python`and `which python3`  -> `/usr/local/bin/python3`. `Which pip` returns nothing. @00

Comment: That just goes to show your v-env was never initialised, despite the command line prompt. I don't know what shell you are using, but try `source venv_x/bin/activate` first (with the appropriate path for the `venv_x` directory.

Comment: @00 the command does not help neither. I checked an older projects workspace, where I know that the venv was working perfectly. It stopped working there too. So it could be a problem with my VS Code installation

Comment: @00 solved it. Only using `pip3 install some_package` works for some weird reason. But not `pip`and not `python pip`.

Comment: @im_baby would you like to post your comment as an answer and maybe explaining why this behaviour occurs? I dont want to mark my own, non-explaining answer as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only `pip3`solved it.

Not using `python pip`or `python3 pip` or `python3 pip3`.

I find that quite weird.

Comment: Perhaps like me, you've added another local Python binary folder to `$PATH` . This was causing me to the local `pip` in spite of having an active `venv`. Removing this from the path variable solved the issue.